# phonegap(cordova) not working on Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

Hey I have just started with windows phone development for phonegap. I have followed all the instructions in the getting started guide and created a phonegap application in  visual studio. But when I run the simulator the index.html is never displayed.
I have even tried to redirect from MainPAge.xaml to index.html but no use. Also I have searched a lot of forums but most of them have inadequate information.

Could someone tell me why this is happening? I'm using VS 2010 and phoneGap 2.5.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tried out PhoneGap 1.7 and 1.3, same output. May be the problem is with the visual studio express that came along with SDK 7.1.

Comment: The problem was that the silverlite xaml file was rendered but as soon as the html file was hit the screen turned black i.e the emulator wasn't capable of rendering the html file
I had to jump through a lot of hoops to figure this out. Hope this helps and saves the effort for some one.

Comment: Finally got it the problem was with the emulator.
The emulator to work properly requires graphic support i.e direct x 9 and above, wddm 1.1 or above.
You can find this information by following these steps,  

1. press windows button + R.  
2. Type command "dxdiag" and hit enter.  
3. Under system and display tag you'll find the required info.